# Is autocorrelation also a problem with data collected from different respondents?

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation

I have a question regarding autocorrelation in multiple linear regression. I analyse data on IPOs over 6 years. I look at a dataset of 450 companies which have listed their stock at the stock exchange. Each company only appears once in the sample, as I am analysing the return of the stock at the first trading day. this is also my dependent variable (so 450 data points for 450 companies) Now my durbin-watson test is 1.09, which indicates positive autocorrelation. I know that this is a problem when looking at time-series data from one respondent/company, but is it also a problem when the companies are different?

Thanks upfront!